# meanio crashed with Error: Cannot find module 'request'

Tags: mean.io

I got the error like this while running meanio app using grunt

```
/home/me/project/myapp/node_modules/meanio/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/project/myapp/packages/contrib/mean-admin/server/controllers/themes.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might be because of mean-admin package in packages/contrib/mean-admin/. In that case just reinstall using mean install command

```
mean install mean-admin
```

Comment: Perhaps it is because mean has been through some updates, but this doesn't work for me. If/when I find a fix I will come and post my answer.